# xPath для Material UI меню

Tags: python, xpath

Используя Chrome driver я тестирую сайт используя Python. Для перехода между страничками и разделами я указываю xPath. Всё бы хорошо, но дизайнер сделал drop-down меню используя Material UI и у меня на этапе выбора выпадающего списка не получается раскрыть этот список и выбрать нужный элемент.

Вот код формы отправки запроса "invite user", в котором надо выбрать тип группы, и вписать е-мейл.

```html
<div class="formAdmin__body">
  <div class="modal-input-wrap">
    <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-marginDense MuiFormControl-fullWidth"><label
        class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-marginDense MuiInputLabel-outlined Mui-required Mui-required"
        data-shrink="false" for="outlined-required">Select group<span
          class="MuiFormLabel-asterisk MuiInputLabel-asterisk"> *</span></label>
      <div
        class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-marginDense MuiOutlinedInput-marginDense">
        <div
          class="MuiSelect-root MuiSelect-select MuiSelect-selectMenu MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputSelect MuiOutlinedInput-inputSelect MuiInputBase-inputMarginDense MuiOutlinedInput-inputMarginDense MuiSelect-outlined"
          tabindex="0" role="button" aria-haspopup="listbox" id="select-group"><span>​</span></div><input name="group"
          type="hidden" id="group" value=""><svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSelect-icon" focusable="false"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
          <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z"></path>
        </svg>
        <fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="jss77 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline" style="padding-left: 49.875px;">
          <legend class="jss78" style="width: 0.01px;"><span>​</span></legend>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-input-wrap">
    <div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root MuiFormControl-marginDense MuiFormControl-fullWidth"><label
        class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-marginDense MuiInputLabel-outlined Mui-required Mui-required"
        data-shrink="false" for="outlined-required">Email<span
          class="MuiFormLabel-asterisk MuiInputLabel-asterisk"> *</span></label>
      <div
        class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-fullWidth MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-marginDense MuiOutlinedInput-marginDense">
        <input aria-invalid="false"
          class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputMarginDense MuiOutlinedInput-inputMarginDense"
          id="outlined-required" name="email" placeholder="Email:" required="" type="text" value="">
        <fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="jss77 MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline" style="padding-left: 31.125px;">
          <legend class="jss78" style="width: 0.01px;"><span>​</span></legend>
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Используя инструменты хрома, F12, потом поиск и выбор элемента формы (блока) указателем мышки, я получаю следующие xPath:

`self.selectGroup = PageObject(self.driver, '//span[text()="Select group"]')
self.viewElement = PageObject(self.driver, '//*[@id="menu-group"]/div[3]/ul')
self.selectElement = PageObject(self.driver, '//*[@id="menu-group"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]')
self.emailField = PageObject(self.driver, '//input[@name="email"]')`

Эти ссылки при поиске элемента "подсвечиваются" в хроме, но при выполении программы авто-тестинга - выдбор меню, и переход по нему не осуществляется. В чём может быть причина, может эти элементы не являются кликабельными, и к ним надо применить другой подход?

Comment: насколько понимаю вы же selenium используете, хотя что-то непохоже? если да, то там есть метод click(), ```some_button = self.driver.find_elemend_by_xpath(xpath) ``` и кликайте на неё ```some_button.click()```

Comment: Да, использую selenium, но получилось xPath написать такой: `//*[@id="app"]/div/main/div/form/div[2]/div[1]` а по кликабельности у меня так и получается: `mainPage.selectGroup.click() mainPage.selectElement.waitElementToBePresent()`